# How to use local variable inside a string in Stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to import multiple files in csv format into Stata. Their names follow the format "variable_2010". I want to use a loop to import and save these files. I tried the following:

```
foreach var in varlist a b c d {
import "c:\`var'_2010.csv"
save ......
}
```

This does not work . The problem is that `var` is not recognised inside the path. How could I escape this problem?

Comment: `var` is here a local macro. People used to other languages may want to call it a variable, but it's not a variable to Stata, but, as said, a local macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be confusion with the use of `foreach`. You probably meant

```
foreach var in a b c d {
   import "c:/`var'_2010.csv"
}
```

The keyword `varlist` is meant to be used with `of` and not `in`. If used in your original way, `varlist` is just text to be used in the looping, which I assume is not what is meant. Read `help foreach` carefully.

You have already discovered the "backstabbing backslash", and that its use is discouraged. Depending on the OS, Stata will translate accordingly, so you should always use `/` when working with file directories.

**Reference:**

[Stata tip 65: Beware the backstabbing backslash](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0042), The Stata Journal, by Nicholas J. Cox.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through similar questions, I seem to have found the answer. This link here http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0042 solve the problem. Just use forward slash instead of backlash.